# How to autoresize UIView with UISegmentedControl in table view header view

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

When I create a `UISegmentedControl` and set it as a table view's header view without assigning any frame to it, the control is automatically sized to span the table view's width and keeps its intrinsic height.

```
let control = UISegmentedControl(items: ["one", "two"])
tableView.tableHeaderView = control
```

[image: simulator screenshot with segmented control properly sized]

However, when I wrap the segmented control inside another `UIView`, the view collapses and is not resized properly.

```
let header = UIView()
let control = UISegmentedControl(items: ["one", "two"])
header.addSubview(control)
tableView.tableHeaderView = header
```

[image: simulator screenshot with segmented control improperly sized]

How can I make the `UIView` behave in the same way as the `UISegmentedControl`? I was not able to find any difference between the two in terms of initial configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering myself here. I found out that initializing the view with an arbitrary-width and desired-height frame and then using autolayout to make the segmented control span the view does the trick.

```
let header = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 33))
let control = UISegmentedControl(items: ["one", "two"])
control.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
header.addSubview(control)
header.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[control]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["control": control]))
header.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[control]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["control": control]))
tableView.tableHeaderView = header
```

It seems that the width of the frame is ignored and that the header view is always resized to the table view's width. Setting a dedicated height is, however, mandatory.

My guess is that

```
UISegmentedControl(items: ["one", "two"])
```

internally calls `init(frame:)` with a default frame which enables this mechanism. On the other hand,

```
UIView()
```

apparently calls `init(frame:)` with a `CGRectZero` which makes the header collapse.

Comment: This still fills the width for me.